# Prevent deletion by Outlook in Professional Edition

Tags: security

We have SFDC PE, and are also using SFDC for Outlook.  We are using 2 way sync for Contacts, and Outlook is always the winner.  We are concerned that if someone accidentally deletes contacts in their Outlook folder, the corresponding contacts will be deleted in SFDC.  Ideally, we would like to prevent this either using object permissions, or triggers, both of which are unavailable in PE.  Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Are you only concerned about deleting contacts through Outlook, or deletion in general?

Comment: Only through Outlook

Comment: One thing I can think of should it be possible in your case, would be to set SF to be the winner. In case you need to control deletion in SF. You can use a new page layout without the delete button perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It's less than ideal and a bit of an Ambulance at the bottom of the cliff solution (treating consequences rather than causes), but you could periodically check the recycle bin and restore the Contacts that were accidentally deleted.

I'd would suggest creating a profile for the user without the delete permission, but I suspect that isn't an option for professional edition either.

Answer (score 0):

Best option I can think of is to build a managed package in a Developer Edition Org that has a trigger to prevent deletion, and then deploy that in your org. Pretty sure that will do the job, but it might have to go through security review.